# Lambda AppSync GraphQL - get string from mutation request - Not Found

Tags: go, aws-lambda, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm using AWS Amplify, AppSync (GraphQL), and a Go Lambda function. I have defined my function as follows

```
type Mutation {
  goadd(name: String): String @function(name: "goadd-${env}")
}
```

The resolver request template is:
[image]

and then my lambda is

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

type MyEvent struct {
    Name  string `json:"name"`
}

func HandleRequest(ctx context.Context, name MyEvent) (string, error) {
    fmt.Printf("Hello %v\n", name.Name)
    fmt.Println(name)
    fmt.Println(ctx)
    return fmt.Sprintf("Hello %s!", name.Name), nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(HandleRequest)
}
```

And the response that I get when I execute a mutation in AppSync is
`Hello !`

I check the CloudWatch logs as well and they don't show any data being passed in.

I tried this same thing using Node.js and it worked without an issue, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong w/ this in Go. Anybody have an idea?

I also read the documentation for `"github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"` and it felt pretty ambiguous as to how to get values being passed in.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer while looking at [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60039002/how-to-capture-aws-appsync-events-inside-serverless-lambda-datasources) StackOverflow answers. This is not a duplicate because the referenced SO post is for a separate issue which incidentally shows the proper way to grab arguments from the request. The solution is that the values passed in are a map of string (in my case) arguments. So instead of

```
Name string `json:"name"`
```

it should be

```
type Arguments struct {
    Arguments map[string]string `json:"arguments"`
}
```

and then you can access the data

```
name := arguments.Arguments["name"]
```

I would prefer to have a struct which contains "Name" and whatever else I pass through as arguments, but this was a quick first step which I wanted to post as an update for how to at least get the data and resolve my issue